# Chrome extension, javascript: Tab giving me an error

Tags: javascript, tabs, google-chrome-extension

This is my most simple function:

```
function do_the_redirect(where_to)
{

                up2 = new Object();
                up2.url =where_to;
                //alert("here");
                chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, up2);

}
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: tab is not defined
```

Comment: Well the `tab` var is really not defined, how do you expect it to work?

Comment: Also you forgot to declare "up2" with `var`.  Don't forget `var`!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

// in background.js

```
function onRequest(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    function do_the_redirect(where_to) {
        var up2 = new Object();
        up2.url = where_to;
        chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, up2);
   };
};
chrome.extension.onRequest.AddListener(onRequest);
```